# How is it possible for Maps in iOS 13 to have location permissions set to "Whilst Using" but provide navigation instructions in the background?

Tags: privacy, geolocation, maps

Whilst taking a look at the apps that have permissions to view my location in iOS 13.2.3 from Settings/Privacy/Location Services, I've noticed that the stock Maps app is only listed as having access to my location "Whilst Using". Interestingly, however, whilst a navigation is in progress I can appear to be able to navigate away from the app to my Home Screen and still receive navigational instructions. Is this due to this app using a different location model to apps downloaded from the App Store? My assumption would be that as soon as I navigate away from Maps, location access should then be withdrawn.

Comment: That would be somewhat counter-productive. You told it to navigate. Until you tell it to stop, you are **using** it by all definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_location_services_authorization_to_request) Apple Developer article:
*"In general, iOS apps are considered in use when they're in the foreground or running in the background with the background location usage indicator enabled."*

Since the navigation is still in progress, the App is running in the background and therefore considered as "in use".